# How to override weblogic application libraries?

Tags: weblogic-10.x

I am developing a plugin for an application that is deployed in Weblogic 10.3.6. I need to use jersey 2.25 api in the plugin. The application ships jersey 1.8 in its APP-INF/lib folder. So, when I deploy the plugin the classes are all mixed up and throws class cast exception. I cannot modify the application. I have deployed the jersey 2.25 jars in DOMAIN_HOME/lib folder. Is there a way to use the new libraries instead of the supplied one in the application? If it is not possible can you suggest me any workaround to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Do you deploy a share-lib which is based on jersey related jars. Remove that share lib. And try again, you may be success. But 10.3.6 don't support jersey 2.25.

Comment: There was a shared lib. I removed it. Although, it solved conflicts with some class, it introduced AbstractMethodError using UriBuilder. So, for now I am trying to rewrite the plugin using jersey 1.8 client api. I also tried to wrap the api in soap service in another domain and access from there. Both working good so far. If you have any suggestion, it will be appreciated.